# sending mouse clicks to another app via sendinput, how to synchronize my c# app to wait for those mouse clicks to be processed?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I currently send mouse clicks via the win32 SendInput (pinvoke), I'm trying to synchronize my app to wait for the mouse clicks to be processed before moving on. I'm trying to avoid using a hard sleep because the time will just add up over millions of instructions over days. I've tried using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_MOUSE_LL in my c# app and while I receive the events it does not appear they have been processed yet by the external app.

Comment: Without being able to make the target app do something to show it's *finished* with an event - or being able to see by some other means that it's finished (some database record or log file appearing?) I'm not sure this is at all possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use UI Automation?

Comment: no nothing like that is avail. what if I were to able to inject myself into the external app using easyhook?

Comment: I was thinking UIAutomation as a possibility, i should try that

Comment: The definition of "processed" is entirely open-ended and depends on how the application (and you) define it. "Processing" could mean repainting a button, or it could mean sending a credit card payment halfway around the world and waiting for the provider to confirm it. Maybe you just mean "retrieved from the input queue"? But that's still no guarantee the app is close to taking appropriate action, or ready to do something else.

Comment: The definition of "processed" would be that the msgs aren't just dequeded but whatever the action clicks invoke are actually performed. let's assume that the code in the external app is sync so when the click occurs it handles it does what ever it needs to (maybe opens a window) then returns and at some point the app becomes settled and then waits for user input

Comment: That assumes the app processes messages perfectly synchronously, which it's not required to do (and most apps don't, to keep the UI responsive). "Whatever it needs to" may well happen on another thread. You can use `Process.Responding` to see if the UI is responding, but in most well-written apps you expect this to be `true` even if it's technically still busy processing stuff.

Comment: If it *is* sync, though, you shouldn't really have much need to check if it's done -- all you need to do is avoid overflowing the queue, which you could do with some modest throttling. A "hard sleep" isn't really going to add up to millions of instructions -- it's not like the OS implements this stuff with busy waiting.

Comment: I'm going to try using the Process.Responding and also UIAutomation  (WaitForInputIdle or WindowInteractionState) on the WindowPattern. I think you misunderstood about the hard sleep not being an option. This is because I am sending millions of instructions to the window not that the hard sleep is generating them (this for long running UI tests that occur over 3 days) so a sleep will increase the time taken over the 3 days

Comment: If you're UI testing, you *definitely* want to take a look at automation, because it's basically designed for those kinds of scenarios -- as opposed to `SendInput`, which is essentially throwing stuff in a black hole. In particular, verifying that Good Things are happening is far easier with automation.